# SQL Server sp_send_dbmail - How to send mail TO Gmail?

Tags: sql-server, sp-send-dbmail

I am using `sp_send_dbmail` which is working perfectly except when I send to recipients using Gmail accounts. The database mail log give the following error:

```
Error,80,The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 2 (2015-05-29T13:22:39). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Unable to send to a recipient.))
```

All recipients not using Gmail receive the mail correctly.

When I use Outlook manually to send messages to this Gmail accounts it is working. The recipients receive the messages correctly. The SQL Server mail account is not using Gmail. I use Port 25 and SSL (I tried without SSL and it is not working either).

Here below the procedure call:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
    @recipients = 'somemail@company.com;somemail@gmail.com',
    @copy_recipients = 'somemail@company.com',
    @profile_name = 'my_profile',
    @subject = 'mail subject',
    @body = 'some content',
    @body_format = 'Text';
```

Comment: Please give the procedure call!

Comment: Hello @GaborRajczi. Procedure call added...

Comment: That message seems to come from the SMTP server, not DBMail. This is not a DBMail issue.

Comment: Can't cause the problem the DMARC protocol?

Answer (score 1):

I tested the sp_send_dbmail proc in SSMS and it works fine for gmail. On the message panel, I got message 'Mail queued'. 
You may trouble shoot the queue using: 
`msdb..sysmail_help_queue_sp @queue_type = 'Mail' ;`

for me, it look like smtp mail relay issue. You should also test you DB mail profile setup.